# User Data Storage Using MVC in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm still new to MVC programming in Java. My question is, in what part of the program is it best practice so store user information? I have a login form and I handle the login in one of my models. What's the best way to make the user data available to the entire application? I was thinking about adding field variables to my model and simply storing the data there, but since I have several models I wouldn't be able to retrieve the data from other models. Is it a good idea to create an object that stores the user data and calling that object from all models? Or is there a better approach? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "user data"? Are you talking about the logged-in user? Use Spring Security, and instead of handling the login yourself let the built-in filter do it for  you.

Comment: This is for a school project, so I'm not too worried about security. I mean simply the login information and other data that is acquired later on.

Comment: The login information **is** security information, and Spring Security handles all of that for you out of the box.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but @chrylis, it seems to me you are either assuming that the OP is using Spring when there's no evidence that they are, or unhelpfully suggesting that they do so. Unhelpful, I think, because it's a school project, and letting a framework do the work means they won't learn how to do it.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion You're right, I read "MVC" and immediately jumped to Spring MVC.

Comment: OP: Tell us more about your program. Is this a Web application or a Swing one? In either case, I still generally recommend using an existing library, but if you're writing a Swing program, I'd say to look at Apache Shiro. Security, including user authentication, is one of the "cross-cutting concerns" that is usually best handled as some sort of filter or aspect applied to the rest of the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

First of your question is too generic an is risking its closure.

Your gut feeling to not mix data is right. Keep whatever user data together. Maybe for now it's just a username but this kind of data tend to grow over time and you want this flexibility later.

Think about where you need that data most. User data is needed for authentication, authorization and tracking.

If you think of the relation of user data and user generated data, or the interaction between content and user data, how would you structure such relations?

If you think about performance, which subset of the user data is at least necessary to fullfil your requirements?

I know I am wage but your question is wage itself.

Try to step back from your code and think more about the architecture of your software.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My question makes sense to me because I've been programming this for three days straight. I will try to be more specific in the future. And thanks for your answer, it did help.